# Doctrine 2: Tree - Nestedset and InnoDB

Tags: tree, nested, doctrine-orm, behavior

I'm using [Doctrine's 2 Tree-Nestedset extension](http://gediminasm.org/article/tree-nestedset-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2) with MySQL InndoDB database.

The *yml* table schema looks like this:

```
Ext\Entity\PageElement:
  type: entity
  table: page_element
  repositoryClass: Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository
  gedmo:
    tree:
      type: nested
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    element_object_data:
      type: array
      nullabe: true
    element_object_type:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    lft:
      type: integer
      gedmo:
        - treeLeft
    rgt:
      type: integer
      gedmo:
        - treeRight
    root:
      type: integer
      gedmo:
        - treeRoot
    lvl:
      type: integer
      gedmo:
        - treeLevel
    sort_order:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    created:
      type: datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
    updated:
      type: datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: update
  manyToOne:
    parent:
      targetEntity: Ext\Entity\PageElement
      inversedBy: children
      gedmo:
        - treeParent
  oneToMany:
    children:
      targetEntity: Ext\Entity\PageElement
      mappedBy: parent
```

Trying to delete any node containing children I get mysql error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`page_element`, CONSTRAINT `page_element_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `page_element` (`id`))

I understand it is because of InnoDB reference restrictions but I'm not sure how to avoid it?

Comment: As a workaround you may delete the related `page_elements` prior to deleting pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is on github [issue tracker](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/133)